# Why is Catwoman so blonde all of a sudden in Gotham S02?

Tags: character, gotham

In Gotham TV series, Catwoman is a poor girl and a small thief. She used to have not so blonde hair.

[image]

But all of a sudden she is a blonde with straight hair rather then curls in S02E20.

[image]

This transformation doesn't go with her character as she is not a parlour kind of girl, who will do stuff like straightening, colouring etc. So what was the reason for this sudden change?

Comment: Wig, used to disguise herself while cat burglary.

Comment: Actually, the second picture looks much more natural to me. Better to ask where a street urchin got the time and money to go get a perm. Lots of make-up in that first picture too. Like prostitute or TV evangelist levels.

Comment: @T.E.D. Because movies and TV **always** make their levels of hair and makeup match the character and their recent actions? How many movies have you seen with a woman waking up with makeup and perfect hair? Or having perfect hair 20 minutes after getting drenched? In a perfect world, you'd be right... but most media just want people to look "pretty".

Comment: I don't remember the end of season 2 but: wasn't she hanging out with Gordon's ex-girlfriend at this point of the series? Also, she was a little bit concerned that Bruce Wayne was seduced by Galavan's relative. Maybe she was trying something?

Comment: @T.E.D. the actress is ‎Camren Bicondova.  Look her up.  The curly hair is her natural hair.

Comment: Why would female superheroines or supervillains be the only category of female humans to not dye their hair as their whims dictate?

Answer (score -3):

I totally agree, but I believe she did a fashion shoot for some designer clothes and they cut and coloured her hair. Its so short at the back that it couldn't possibly be curled again. Maybe it was near the end of shooting ( most episodes are not shot in order) and so they just put a hat on her and hoped for the best. But yep totally out of character.

Comment: Any source for the information?

Comment: You'll want to provide a source for this information, otherwise, it needs to be turned into a comment instead. Welcome to the T&M Stack!!